# Batch Script execution with .exe and powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exe

I want to execute a script thank to Task scheduler in Windows environment.
This script has two parts one part is a PowerShell script command and the other one is starting a program.exe command.

I want them in the same script and launch them one after another and have a message of error if the script failed.
I have a script like this :

```
@echo off
cd "C:\App\Extract_Spool\" & Start program.exe
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\App\Script\Script_Extraction\script.ps1"" -Verb RunAs
pause
```

When I execute all the script it seems not to work. But when I start independently the exe program or the PowerShell one it works.

Do you know why ? Can  you please help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Should this line ```cd "C:\App\Extract_Spool\" & Start program.exe``` be this instead ```cd "C:\App\Extract_Spool\" && Start program.exe``` ? (&& vs &)

Comment: Well I'd suggest it could be, `Start "" /D "C:\App\Extract_Spool" "C:\App\Extract_Spool\program.exe"`, however it's kind of irrelevant to the issue. The issue is probably that when you elevate, the working directory changes to `C:\Windows\System32` not the `C:\App\Extract_Spool` directory you'd previously stipulated. Also there's no need for two pairs of doublequotes, just one should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to run your PowerShell script *elevated* (as admin), as `-Verb RunAs` implies, you must call the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) cmdlet from *within* the PowerShell process, which means that you must use the `-Command` (`-c`) rather than the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell '-NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass', '-File', C:\App\Script\Script_Extraction\script.ps1"
```

Note:

- *Another* `powershell.exe` process is needed in order to invoke the script with elevation.
- In *Windows PowerShell* (PowerShell versions up to v5.1), the elevated session's working directory will be `C:\Windows\System32`; in PowerShell [Core] v6+, the caller's working directory is inherited. In both editions you can use the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to specify a working directly explicitly.
- Both `program.exe` and your elevated script will run in a *new* console window each.